# How to write a method (that takes in a file directory) to extract text from word documents in a file directory?

Tags: python, ms-word, data-extraction

I would like to create a method that can do the actions below, may I know how to do it?:

```
 import os
    import docx2txt

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\FYP\\dataprep\\source_documents")


def get_ednotes(list_all_files):
    #get the file directory
    list_all_files = os.getcwd()
    my_text = docx2txt.process(list_all_files)

    #extract text from file
    #store extracted data in an array
    #return array
```

Comment: can you show us your effort...what you tried so far?

Comment: @Narendra the commented I dont really know the logic :(

Comment: have you searched in google? this is almost redundant, python has built-in functions for this, nothing complicated needed

Comment: Read about [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir). [Edit] your Question if you get stuck with it.

Answer (score -1):

The following documentation gives you the answer:

[Python Input/Output documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

More specifically you require the function `file.readlines()`